# Error creating temp table

Tags: mysql, temp-tables, create-table, derived-table

I am attempting to create a temp table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `test_table` (
  `test` DATE NOT NULL
);
```

Even if i try other schemas i get the following error

```
Can't create table 'db.test_table' (errno: -1)
```

I tried to google -1 error with no luck.

Comment: Do you have the rights to create tables? Try modifying an existing table.

Comment: Ok, we can exclude a "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES privilege" problem. Do you use "apparmor" or other security software, which might have an impact on MySQL's behaviour?

Comment: I think i figured it out. You had to explicitly say ENGINE=MEMORY;

Comment: Hmm, strange. I think this query should work without specifying the ENGINE. Because MySQL would use the default engine (MyISAM), if no engine is specified. Anyway glad you figured it out..

Comment: You shouldn't be limited to the MEMORY engine for temp tables. I would guess that you've changed tmpdir and selinux/apparmor is not letting mysqld create files in the new location.

Comment: Yes we have. Its on a instance storage. What are the steps to fix this with app armor?  The new location is /dir/tmpfs .

Answer (score 2):

Let's summarize:

1. Make sure you have the privilege to "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES"
2. You might need to specify the exact ENGINE you want to use

   ```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `test_table` (
      `test` DATE NOT NULL
   ) ENGINE=MEMORY;
   ```
3. Make sure that security software, like "apparmor", doesn't have impact on MySQLs behaviour by looking at it's configuration. Especially "tmpdir" protection.

Steps to change the apparmor temp dir:

1. create new folder and change ownership to mysql

   ```
   mkdir /mnt/foo/tmp 
   sudo chown mysql:mysql /mnt/foo/tmp
   ```
2. edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to let MySQL use the new tmpdir

   ```
   tmpdir = /mnt/foo/tmp
   ```
3. edit `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld` to allowing reading and writing to the folder

   ```
   /mnt/foo/tmp/ r,
   /mnt/foo/tmp/** rw,
   ```
4. restart services

   ```
   sudo service apparmor reload
   sudo service mysql restart
   ```

Comment: I was able to create a non memory table by specifying engine:

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `test_table` (
  `test` DATE NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM